# Kubernetes Force HorizontalPodAutoscaler to scale up temporarily

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

does anyone know if there is a way that I can force Kubernetes to scale up a deployment using the HPA autoscaler?

e.g something like `kubectl myHPA -scaleUp replicas-count=4` basically I want to temporarily add replicas but then those replicas respect the scaleDown rules of the autoscaler.

The reason for this is that we run simulations on demand, I just want the user to choose the number of replicas before running a simulation for a better user experience.

NB : to save on costs we scale from 0 also, which is why the metrics scaling is difficult to implement. We use KEDA also but as we also use Azure Virtual Nodes with ACI the pods can take up to 2 minutes to provision.

Thanks for looking

Comment: Do you need the pods to be alive for any particular length of time, or just long enough to trigger the cluster autoscaler?  I'd hypothesize if you `kubectl scale deployment myDeployment --replicas=4` it would start creating the pods before HPA would decide to scale back down (but haven't personally tried it).

Comment: Only just got back round to this, yes as you suspected the HPA terminates the replicas straight away.